# Platform-independent directory

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, platform-independent, fhs

Does ASP.NET Core offer any platform-independent way to access standard paths, such as where data or configure files are supposed to be saved?  Modules such as [Qt's  QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) are very helpful to prepare Qt applications to be deployed in a platform-independent way, but unfortunately I haven't found any similar service in ASP.NET Core.  Does anyone know if anything like that exists in the .Net core or ASP.NET Core platforms?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netcore-2.1

Comment: @JoeAudette thanks for the link.  However, `System.IO.Path` was designed to perform operations on path information.  What I was looking for is something like Qt's `QStandardPaths`, which return which path should be used for certain uses such as, say, store config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Environment.GetFolderPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netcore-2.1).

This [blog post](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/07/dotnet-special-folder-api-linux/) provides more info on how the API behaves cross-platform.